# Spring Data MongoRepositories DtoInstantiatingConverter

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-mongodb

I have

```
@Document
public class Employee
{
 @Id
 Long empCode;
 String empSurname;
 String address;
// getters setters
}
```

I have written a query using Mongo Repositories like

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends MongoRepository<Employee, Long>
{

List<Employee> findEmployeesByEmpCode(int empCode);

@Query(value="{ 'empCode' : ?0 }", fields="{ 'address' : 1}")
List<String> findAddressByEmpCode(int empCode);
```

The first query works but the second fails. It works only if I change the returned type of List to Employee.

The error at failure is

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] - this argument is required; it must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115)
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:126)
    at org.springframework.data.convert.EntityInstantiators.getInstantiatorFor(EntityInstantiators.java:86)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.DtoInstantiatingConverter.<init>(DtoInstantiatingConverter.java:61)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoQueryExecution$ResultProcessingConverter.convert(MongoQueryExecution.java:376)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoQueryExecution$ResultProcessingExecution.execute(MongoQueryExecution.java:345)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.execute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:91)
```

Obviously, it cannot work out how to convert the values from the contained Employee object to String.
How can I implement this ? Any example would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fields` attribute is used to filter properties which are not set into your domain objects (`Employee`). It has not much to do with MongoDB projection mechanism.

In order to use projection here, see [projections in the reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#projections).

You will have to create a projection interface:

`interface AddressesProjection { String getAddress(); }`

and change the repository method signature accordingly:

`List<AddressesProjection> findByEmpCode(int empCode);`

> > Projections declare a contract between the underlying type and the method signatures related to the exposed properties. Hence it is required to name getter methods according to the property name of the underlying type.

This is the closest you can get, afaik.

Comment: Thanks very much @Ori. That is exactly what was required.

Comment: I can't seem to return a List back from the projection. It just gives me the first matching element. If I run the query in the console, I get a List of values back. The projection is iike this     @Value("#{target.address}")
    public List<String> getStringValue();

Comment: @John. Didn't really understand you comment. Are you still facing problems? Also, since you query by the `@Id` property (`empCode`), a single result is expected.

Comment: Hi @Ori, You have put me on the right track as far as using Projections is concerned. To clarify my question, I have edited my example. Basically my query is List<String> findEmployeesByEmpSurname(String surName);
I am hoping to have multiple addresses returned in a List for a given Surname which can have multiple matches in the table. Currently it just returns the first match in the List. If I run the generated query on the command line, I get several documents returned.